# copying a range from an Excel workbook to another workbook using sheet range

Tags: excel, vba

It looks like my code is not copying the range over, but when I tested it with a string it would copy over.

Here is my code:

```
    With setupSheet
        setupSheet.Range("BA1:BB7") = sheet1.Range("A2:B8")
    End With
```

Nothing is getting replaced in setupSheet.

Comment: *it looks like my code is not copyign the range over* - this is not very clear. Can you be more specific? Maybe with screenshots? Also, is `Sheet1.Range("A2:B8")` formulas?

Comment: Although the default property of `Range` is `Value`, it appears to be required in this statement.  Try `.Range("BA1:BB7").Value = sheet1.Range("A2:B8").Value`. Better still try `.Range("BA1:BB7").Copy Destination := sheet1.Range("A2")`.  `Copy` only requires the top, left cell of the destination.  It also copies formats.

Comment: .value fixed it.  thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

The point of the with statement is so that you don't have to keep typing the expression

Try this:

```
  With setupSheet
    .Range("BA1:BB7") = sheet1.Range("A2:B8")
  End With
```

Comment: yeah i know but i tried without the with and its not working,